# Como retornar o tratamento de dados em Matriz passada como parâmetro para rotinas no VBA/Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, matriz

Preciso passar **matrizes distintas** para uma rotina que ordena seus elementos e recebem outros tratamentos, e após isso quero que ela retorne esses valores ordenados e tratados para a **matriz original**; por exemplo, passei valores fora de ordem e alguns fracionados para a rotina por meio de uma matriz, primeiro os valores fracionados são arredondados e depois ordenados, para então retornarem para a matriz que "alimentou" a rotina desta forma (sem as casas decimais e ordenados).

Primeiro os dados são retirados de uma planilha no **Excel** e preenchem as matrizes que irei tratar. Estes dados não podem ser alterados, pois trata-se de dados de digitação e devem permanecer na ordem e como foram digitados, de qualquer forma, preciso resolver estes casos somente pelo **VBA**.

A ideia é ter uma rotina que trate a matriz passada para ela, o que funciona, mas que os valores da matriz original, recebam de volta os valores tratados; isto eu não consegui fazer nem encontrar como fazer.

Pesquisei sobre isso para o **VBA**, mas o que encontrei só faz referência em **usar esses valores da matriz dentro da rotina**, porém **não devolvendo o resultado para a matriz original**.

O exemplo abaixo foi retirado do **link**:

[Noções básicas sobre matrizes do parâmetro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/gg264243.aspx)

O exemplo funciona para receber e manipular esses valores, porém preciso ter os resultados retornados para a matriz original que no meu caso tratam-se de variáveis dimensionadas, e não somente de dados como mostra este exemplo.

**Tem como fazer isso no VBA/Excel?**

> O exemplo a seguir mostra como você pode definir um procedimento com
>   uma matriz de parâmetros.

```
Sub AnyNumberArgs(strName As String, ParamArray intScores() As Variant) 

     Dim intI As Integer 

     Debug.Print strName; " Scores" 

   ' Use UBound function to determine upper limit of array. 
     For intI = 0 To UBound(intScores()) 

         Debug.Print " "; intScores(intI) 

     Next intI 

End Sub
```

> Os exemplos a seguir mostram como você pode chamar esse procedimento.

```
AnyNumberArgs "Jamie", 10, 26, 32, 15, 22, 24, 16 

AnyNumberArgs "Kelly", "High", "Low", "Average", "High"
```

Basicamente os testes que fiz tiveram este formato, no entanto fiz inúmeras tentativas mudando a forma de usar as matrizes, de chamada da função, mudando o tipo de variável declarada na função, etc. Como o básico não funcionou. não tenho o código completo, pois busquei testar primeiro antes de fazer a rotina, já que nunca tinha feito isto antes: Usei função, pois a ideia é que ela "retorne" com os dados tratados e não fiz declarações públicas, pois queria saber se funcionaria desta forma. Portanto, o código abaixo apresenta a estrutura da ideia de como tentar resolver o problema:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ...
    ...

    MatrizA() = TrataDepoisRetornaMatriz( MatrizA(), QtdeDeItensDaMatrizA )

    MatrizB() = TrataDepoisRetornaMatriz( MatrizB(), QtdeDeItensDaMatrizB )

    MatrizC() = TrataDepoisRetornaMatriz( MatrizC(), QtdeDeItensDaMatrizC )

    ...
    ...
    ...
End Sub


Private Function TrataDepoisRetornaMatriz( _
      ParamArray Matriz() As Variant, _
           Byval QtdeDeItensDaMatriz As Integer) _
              As Variant
    ...
    ...
    ...

    TrataDepoisRetornaMatriz = Matriz()

End Function
```

Comment: Quando vc diz que a ordenação da matriz "passada" funciona, porém não consegue retornar para esses valores para a matriz original... essa matriz original seria, ou estariam, em uma planilha/tabela? Pois poderia fazer uma macro simples para ordenar a coluna desejada... se não for isso, acho que não entendi direito... desculpe-me

Comment: Evert, os dados são somente retirados da planilha, não retornam. Um exemplo: as matrizes (vetores) A, B e C pegaram três grupos de dados distintos da planilha. Tem a função/rotina (testei os dois casos), OrdenaDados, que passo como parâmetro um vetor por vez que quero ordenar, informando o vetor (A, B ou C) e a respectiva quantidade de itens para ordenação. São três chamadas da função. Como apresento os dados de A, B e C depois, preciso que eles tenham o resultado da ordenação. É isso.

Comment: Evert, sei que parece estranho eu não ordenar primeiro na planilha, é que eu apresentei o problema simplificado, meu caso é mais complexo e não se trata só de ordenar os dados, eles são tratados também. Se funcionar para esse caso, funcionará também para o que eu preciso, é isso amigo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para melhor esclarecer.

Comment: onde vc declarou sua matriz? Em um módulo? Ou está tratando como classes? Creio que se tiver a matriz 1 declarada globalmente, não vai precisar de duas... pegue a matriz com os dados, faça as alterações nos valores, dentro da própria função tenha uma matriz temporária e retorne a matriz preenchida como precisa.... Caso ainda não consiga assim, mostre como fez sua implementação, mostre seu código para facilitar a identificação da melhor forma de utilizar. Esse código da microsoft roda ok, mas como foi a sua implementação?

Comment: Eu não coloquei o código pois o que fiz não funcionou de várias formas que tentei, o código é o próprio do formulário, não fiz em módulo separado nem criei uma classe (não trabalhei com classes ainda, mas gostaria). Vou rascunhar uma chamada.

Comment: É que comentou em sua pergunta que funcionou a ordenação... verei hj no trabalho que tenho Excel.

Comment: Oi Evert, eu editei a pergunta, o "exemplo" é que funciona ao receber os dados da matriz, isso eu também consegui, mas retornar os dados após alguma modificação na rotina é que não consegui.

Comment: Leo, não tenho Excel em casa... agora que entendi o que vc não consegue... na segunda te envio uma função retornando os dados... mas se fizer como fez mesmo, vai conseguir, colocando os dados lidos em um array e retornando como função ou colocando um array declarado como global. Veja aqui como fazer http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/index.php/the-complete-guide-to-using-arrays-in-excel-vba/, desculpe não poder ajudar de maneira completa... mas abandonei windows para desenvolvimento. Na segunda respondeirei sua pergunta e creio que será a contento. Abraço e bom fds

Comment: Evert, obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente e sem declarar a variável como Pública. Aguardo teu exemplo para marcar a resposta e votar. O link é didático, excelente. Valeu!

Comment: Oi Evert, você irá postar a resposta? Se for eu aguardo, senão me avisa que eu posto para não ficar sem resposta.

Comment: Oh Leo não tive tempo. Pode postar ai que já deve ter até a rotina de ordenar que teria de fazer aqui, acho que ficará mais completa. Abs e Obrigado pela consideração. Se quiser marque meu comentário com o link como útil à resposta. Abraço

Comment: Valeu pela dica, abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A solução é apresentada no código abaixo.**

O exemplo do código é simplificado para mostrar com pequenas adaptações ao link    http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/index.php/the-complete-guide-to-using-arrays-in-excel-vba/ indicado pelo **Evert**, como fazer funcionar a **principal necessidade**: "passar dados de uma matriz para uma outra matriz em uma função e ter os resultados desta matriz tratados nesta função retornados para a matriz que a alimentou.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Integer

    ' Declare dynamic array - not allocated
    Dim arr() As String

    ' Return new array
    arr = GetArray

    For i = 0 To 5

        MsgBox arr(i)

    Next i

End Sub


Public Function GetArray() As String()

    Dim i As Integer

    ' Create and allocate new array
    Dim arr(0 To 5) As String

    ' Return array

    For i = 0 To 5

        arr(i) = i & " elevado ao quadrado é igual a " & i ^ 2

    Next i

    GetArray = arr

End Function
```

Claro que da mesma forma podem ser feitos os tratamentos citados na pergunta, como a ordenação de dados, por exemplo, mas a questão não é o tratamento em si, e sim a solução deste problema de transferir e receber valor de matrizes em uma função.